# How to create custom field in Jira which can do a multiplication of two other ones?

Tags: jira

I need to create a field which can do a multiplication of severity and priority. I've found how to create a field, I know I must add a script to Description section. But the problem is that I can't figure out how to get these two fields for the operation. Probably it should be something like this:

```
<!-- @@Formula: 

return (issue.getSeverity() * issue.getPriority()) 

-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have two fields, one custom, and one system. So it looks like this:

```
<!-- @@Formula: 
int severityValue = 0;
int priorityValue = 0;

if(issue.get("priority").getName() == null) return 0;
if(issue.get("customfield_12006") == null) return 0;

String severity = issue.get("customfield_12006");
String priority = issue.get("priority").getName();

switch(severity) {
    case "S1": {
        severityValue = 5;
        break;
    }
    case "S2": {
        severityValue = 4;
        break;
    }
    case "S3": {
        severityValue = 3;
        break;
    }
    case "S4": {
        severityValue = 2;
        break;
    }
    case "S5": {
        severityValue = 1;
        break;
    }
}

switch(priority) {
    case "Blocker": {
        priorityValue = 5;
        break;
    }
    case "Critical": {
        priorityValue = 4;
        break;
    }
    case "Major": {
        priorityValue = 3;
        break;
    }
    case "Minor": {
        priorityValue = 2;
        break;
    }
    case "Trivial": {
        priorityValue = 1;
        break;
    }
}
return (severityValue * priorityValue)
-->
```

You can get issue id this way: "https://base_jira_url/rest/api/2/field".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free plugin [Jira Misc Custom Fields](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.innovalog.jmcf.jira-misc-custom-fields/server/overview) that provides a field named "Calculated Number Field".

If you need more complex operations you can try the powerful [Jira Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) plugin and use the Scripted field: by using the Groovy language you can create even the most complex calculations.